# Why isn't my heroku app using secure connection

Tags: heroku, lets-encrypt

I recently upgraded from free account to hobby account on heroku by using following command:

```
 heroku ps:resize web=hobby
```

The I enabled the automated certificate management with following command:

```
 heroku certs:auto:enable
```

after waiting a couple of hours i decided to run:

```
heroku certs:auto
```

and according to my status description it's running ok.

I even ran the following command:

```
curl -vI https://www.yaknchat.com
```

which tells me my server certification verification is OK.

However, when i enter https://www.yaknchat.com in the browser it tells me "this connect is not FULLY secure" as opposed to the usual response "this connect is not secure".

I'am doing something wrong. Should I go into my namescheap advanced DNS settings and change CNAME or AAA Record? Also, is it required to use SSL Endpoint (heroku addon) to get secure green bar for my app url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are linking to insecure resources:

```
<img alt="feature pic" src="http://~~~.png" width="286" height="180" />
```

You need to use https for your page, *and* any resources that it loads for your browser not to complain. `curl` works fine because it only fetches the html and not the linked insecure images.

Comment: OMG you are the man bro! I changed the image http to https just as you suggested and pushed new code to repo and bam green bar on my site. Thanks a bunch!  :)